# Why does the "[]" operator of std::map<std::string, std::string> accept a double value but gives unexpected output?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

We came around the following code snipped:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
m["a"] = 42.0;
std::cout << "value=" << m["a"] << std::endl;
```

Output is:

```
value=*
```

It works with all compilers that we tested (via GodBolt). Obviously, the double value 42.0 is implicitly converted to a char (ASCII of 42 is "*"). That was not expected and we find it rather dangerous behaviour.

Why does it work like this? What could we do to avoid such hard-to-find errors?

Comment: Your question is reducible to "why can I assign a double to a `std::string`?" - [live example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caf72ccde6d57e7d)

Comment: You could find/write clang-tidy checks to cover the dangerous cases you can precisely specify, and you can have good tests, but the highly unfortunate conversion itself isn't likely to be going anywhere.

Comment: But `std::string s = 42.0;` does not compile, as I would expect:

`error: conversion from 'double' to non-scalar type 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} requested`

In contrast, the map assignment works.

Comment: Ah, If done in 2 steps, as @alter_igel did, it compiles: `std::string s; s= 42.0;` That's a subtle difference and somehow feels like unstable behaviour.